# Seeking birth record for Jacob Schulthess from Wangen an der Aare in Switzerland?

Tags: birth-records, 1890s, switzerland

I'm just getting started researching my husband's family who came from Wangen an der Aare, Bern Canton, Switzerland.

I'm looking for Jacob Schulthess birth record who was born 29 Jan 1892 in Wangen an der Aare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wangen an der Aare death record Jacob Schulthess](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13572/wangen-an-der-aare-death-record-jacob-schulthess)

Comment: @lejonet I've made a duplicate to work in the opposite direction from the original "two question question" to the two new questions that have been split from it.