# Seeking death record for Jacob Schulthess who died in Wangen an der Aare prison in Switzerland?

Tags: death-records, 1890s, switzerland, imprisonment

Looking for the death record for Jacob Schulthess who died in Wangen an der Aare prison sometime between   1894 - Oct 1899

I am told he was sent to prison for accidentally shooting his mother in law (intending to shoot his wife who was having an affair with another man).

His son was born in 1894. His mother in law Anna "Barbara" Obreht died (I think) 23 Nov 1895    His wife Emma Obrecht remarried in Bern Canton on Oct 1899.  Jacob died sometime in between those 2 dates.  Jacob was an accountant.